# what is the reason of java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 error in code?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio

i have this error in my code:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nooshindroid.yastashir/com.nooshindroid.yastashir.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

in dess3  and dess 4 this error has accurred!
idon't know why .but the size of dess3 and dess 4 is 0!

Route class of this code is here:

```
    public class Route  extends Activity {
String diff;
Context context;
ArrayList<String> sources, destinations,   destinations2,destinations3,destinations4, answer;
public static ArrayList<Models> routeItems;
public Route(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


  public Route(String part) {

    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
    try {
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        diff = bundle.getString("level");


        InputStream in_s = this.context.getAssets().open(diff);
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in_s, null);

        parseXML(parser);

    }
    catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    Models currentRout = null;

    sources = new ArrayList<String>();
    sources.clear();

    destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
    destinations.clear();

    destinations2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    destinations2.clear();

    destinations3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    destinations3.clear();

    destinations4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    destinations4.clear();

    answer = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer.clear();



    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String name = null;
        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                routeItems = new ArrayList<Models>();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                    currentRout = new Models();
                } else if (currentRout != null) {
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("source")) {
                        currentRout.source = parser.nextText();
                        if ( !sources.contains(currentRout.source))
                            sources.add(currentRout.source);
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("destination")) {
                        currentRout.destination = parser.nextText();
                        try {
                            //if ( !destinations.contains(currentRout.destination))
                            destinations.add(currentRout.destination);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("destination2")) {
                        currentRout.destination2 = parser.nextText();
                        try {

                            //if ( !destinations2.contains(currentRout.destination2))
                            destinations2.add(currentRout.destination2);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }


                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("destination2")) {
                        currentRout.destination3 = parser.nextText();
                        try {
                            //if ( !destinations2.contains(currentRout.destination2))
                            destinations3.add(currentRout.destination3);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("destination2")) {
                        currentRout.destination4 = parser.nextText();
                        try {
                            //if ( !destinations2.contains(currentRout.destination2))
                            destinations4.add(currentRout.destination4);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("answer")) {
                        currentRout.answer = parser.nextText();
                        try {
                            //if ( !destinations2.contains(currentRout.destination2))
                            answer.add(currentRout.answer);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("route") && currentRout != null) {
                    routeItems.add(currentRout);
                }
        }

        eventType = parser.next();
    }
}
}
```

main activiy of my code is as bellow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public int nextque;


ArrayList<String> sourcess;
ArrayList<String> dess;
ArrayList<String> dess2;
ArrayList<String> dess3;
ArrayList<String> dess4;
ArrayList<String> answer;


int randomInt;
Random random;





Button buttons[] = new Button[8];
String j[] = new String[3];
int sumscore1 = 0;
int sumscore2 = 0;
String diff;
ProgressBar mProgressBar, mProgressBar1;
int edtTimerValue;
TextView textViewShowTime;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds;
public void nextque() {
    if ((nextque) + 1 <  sourcess.size()) {
        nextque++;

    }
}
private void setTimer() {
    int time = 0;
    time = edtTimerValue;
    totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = time * 1000;
    mProgressBar1.setMax(time * 1000);
}
public void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 1) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
            mProgressBar1.setProgress((int) (leftTimeInMilliseconds));


            textViewShowTime.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            buttons[7].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank_button);
            textViewShowTime.setText("10");
            textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextStep();

        }
    }.start();
}

public void nextStep() {


    textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    equation1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    equation2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setTimer();
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    startTimer();
    mProgressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(sumscore1==100){
        sumscore1=0;
        sumscore2=0;
        score1.setText(String.valueOf(sumscore1));
        score2.setText(String.valueOf(sumscore2));
    }
    if (sumscore2==100){
        sumscore1=0;
        sumscore2=0;
        score1.setText(String.valueOf(sumscore1));
        score2.setText(String.valueOf(sumscore2));
    }
    random = new Random();
    randomInt = random.nextInt(sourcess.size());
    equation1.setText(sourcess.get(nextque));
    equation2.setText(sourcess.get(nextque));

    Random rn = new Random();
    int index = rn.nextInt(3) + 0;
    Log.e("rand poduct", String.valueOf(index));
    nextque();
    equation1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.equation1);
    buttons[index].setText( answer.get(nextque));
    dess.size();
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        Log.e("prod", "loop " + i);
        if (i != index ) {
            if(!(answer.get(nextque).equals(j[k]))){
                buttons[i].setText((j[k]));
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
    equation2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.equation2);
    Random rt = new Random();
    int index2 = rt.nextInt(3) + 0;
    int index3 = index2 + 4;
    buttons[index3].setText( answer.get(nextque));
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i <= 7; i++) {
        if (i != index3) {
            if(!(answer.get(nextque).equals(j[d]))){
                buttons[i].setText((j[d]));
            }
            d++;
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    equal1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.equal1);
    equal2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.equal2);
    bord1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bord1);
    bord2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bord2);
    bakht1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bakht1);
    bakht2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bakht2);
    refreash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreash);
    textViewShowTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_timerview_time);
    edtTimerValue = 10;
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_timerview);
    mProgressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar1_timerview);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BYekan.ttf");
    diff = bundle.getString("level");
    textViewShowTime.setTypeface(font);
    route = new Route(getApplicationContext());
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
    try {
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("easys.xml");
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in_s, null);

        route.parseXML(parser);

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sourcess = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < route.sources.size(); i++) {
        sourcess.add(i, route.sources.get(i));
    }
    dess = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < route.destinations.size(); i++) {
        dess.add(i, route.destinations.get(i));
    }
    dess2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < route.destinations2.size(); i++) {
        dess2.add(i, route.destinations2.get(i));
    }
    dess3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < route.destinations3.size(); i++) {
        dess3.add(i, route.destinations3.get(i));
    }
    dess4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < route.destinations4.size(); i++) {
        dess4.add(i, route.destinations4.get(i));
    }
    answer = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < route.answer.size(); i++) {
        answer.add(i, route.answer.get(i));

    }
    nextStep();
}
}
```

can anyone help me to solve it?thank alot for your attention.

Comment: most likely `destinations3` array list is empty. If you are trying to get n+1 element from an array list whose size is n then you'll get this exception.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried debug your code?

Comment: no i can't..i get log  in Rout class to find the size of destinations3 and destinations 4  and destinationas ...result was in this way:size of destinations= 21 but size of destination3 and destinations4 is 0..but i do'nt know why the size of destinations 3 and destinations 4 is 0

Answer (score 0):

The array size of array j is 3. But when you are using it inside the loop, you are iterating it more than its size.. Try increasing the size of the arrays and check.

Along with the error you get the line number too of the error, post it if possible.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yeah I am not allowed to comment until i reach 50. Thought of mentioning it in the answer but that skipped out of my mind..

Comment: tnk for your answer ...i check j ...i think it is ok... and my problem is not solved yet